# Fix position for EmpName column of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I have bind my sql data source to gridview, in which the first column is of EmpName with 1000 of records.My problem is when I **scroll horizontally** the first column gets hide.
Problem is I want maintain **header and EmpName of gridview fixed while scrolling**.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/614041/GridView-with-Fixed-Header-and-Scroll-Bar

Comment: @Zaki: but its just for fixed header... I also need to fixed column...

Comment: What you have tried so far. Kindly put that in your question.